# Stop a loop if a certain character is passed to it Ruby

Tags: ruby

So I am working on a small assignment to transcribe DNA strands to RNA strands. My current code looks like this:

```
class Complement
  def self.of_dna(str)
    dna_rna = { 'G' => 'C', 'C' => 'G', 'T' => 'A', 'A' => 'U' }
    rna = []
    str.scan(/[GCTA]/).each do |x|
      rna << dna_rna[x]
    end
    rna.join('')
  end
end
```

It works perfectly, except for in one situation. If a DNA strand is passed that is partially correct, for example `ACGTXXXCTTAA`, my method will translate the DNA to RNA and just leave out the X's, giving me a result of `UGCAGAAUU` rather than just `""`. How can I make it so the loop will fail and exit when it receives a letter that isn't DNA related?

EDIT:
The test I am trying to get to pass looks like this:

```
def test_dna_correctly_handles_partially_invalid_input
  # skip
  assert_equal '', Complement.of_dna('ACGTXXXCTTAA')
end
```

I attempted @Holger Just's idea from below, and received this error:

```
 1) Error:
ComplementTest#test_dna_correctly_handles_completely_invalid_input:
ArgumentError: ArgumentError
    /Users/LukasBarry/exercism/ruby/rna-transcription/rna_transcription.rb:6:in `block in of_dna'
    /Users/LukasBarry/exercism/ruby/rna-transcription/rna_transcription.rb:5:in `each'
    /Users/LukasBarry/exercism/ruby/rna-transcription/rna_transcription.rb:5:in `of_dna'
    rna_transcription_test.rb:43:in `test_dna_correctly_handles_completely_invalid_input'
```

The usual failure I've been getting from the above method is this:

```
1) Failure:
ComplementTest#test_dna_correctly_handles_partially_invalid_input [rna_transcription_test.rb:48]:
Expected: ""
  Actual: "UGCAGAAUU"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
class Complement
  def self.of_dna(str)
    return "" if str =~ /[^GCTA]/
    ...
  end
end
```

Fun fact, you don't even need a loop to replace characters

```
str = 'GATTACA'
str.tr('ATCG', 'UAGC')
# => 'CUAAUGU'
```

Is all you need.

Comment: Beat me to it! But this answer ensures ANY invalid character results in an empty string being returned. I'm not sure the accepted answer is really what the OP wants - in his question he said X was just 'for example`...

Comment: I tried this and it worked as well! Thanks! I love seeing multiple answers that work.

Comment: I also switched the correct answer to this one as @soupdog is correct, this way handles any incorrect letter being passed, and while I was only looking to solve for 'X' being passed, this is ultimately a better solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Technically you don't need a regex either: `'GCGCTA'.tr('ATCG', 'UAGC')`

Answer (score 1):

You can also match `X` in your regex and perform some erorr handling if it is found in the string. This could look something like this:

```
class Complement
  def self.of_dna(str)
    dna_rna = { 'G' => 'C', 'C' => 'G', 'T' => 'A', 'A' => 'U' }
    rna = []
    str.scan(/[GCTAX]/).each do |x|
      return '' if x == 'X'
      rna << dna_rna[x]
    end
    rna.join('')
  end
end
```

Comment: I like it, but I tried to run it and got an error. I will edit my question to add more info about the error. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the whole point of the added error handling was for an Exception to be thrown :) I have just edited my response so that the method returns an empty string in case there are any `X` characters in the string as you mentioned in your question. However, this is probably a suboptimal solution in practice as you have no way to distinguish between a valid result with an empty input string and an invalid result when given an incomplete DNA strand.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `Hash#fetch` for this because it'll raise a `KeyError` for you on mismatch, allowing you to write less code that validates inputs (i.e., less defensive programming), which I think is more valuable than cleverness (in which case I would recommend [String#tr](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr)).

```
class DNA
  TranslationMap = { 'G' => 'C', 'C' => 'G', 'T' => 'A', 'A' => 'U' }
  attr_reader :dna

  def initialize(dna)
    @dna = dna
  end

  def to_rna
    dna.each_char.map do |nucleotide|
      TranslationMap.fetch(nucleotide)
    end.join('')
  rescue KeyError
    return false
  end
end
```

Feel free to adapt what happens when the error is rescued to fit your needs. I recommend raising a more specific exception (e.g. `DNA::InvalidNucleotide`) for the caller to handle.

In use:

```
dna = DNA.new 'GCTA'
 # => #<DNA:0x007fc49e903818 @dna="GCTA"> 
dna.to_rna
 # => "CGAU" 
dna = DNA.new 'ACGTXXXCTTAA'
 # => #<DNA:0x007fc49f064800 @dna="ACGTXXXCTTAA"> 
dna.to_rna
 # => false
```

Comment: I like. Perhaps `TranslationMap.fetch(nucleotide) { return false }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I suppose it depends on the context: do we expect invalid nucleotides, or is it truly an exceptional condition that we merely intend to handle without total failure?

Comment: Doesn't the line I suggested do exactly what your code does? I am of course suggesting that in place of the `rescue` clause.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Functionally it's the same, it's a matter of revealing intent in the code. So writing for other developers more than just the machine. Either will work, but only one reveals that the behavior is unexpected. :)

Comment: OK, then `TranslationMap.fetch(nucleotide) { return false } # block deals with unexpected behaviour`. :-)